# Android Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP crash

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, webp

When I try to store `Bitmap` using

`Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 80, out);`

The application crash with error

`A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x82a80000 in tid 28896 (AsyncTask #4)`

My code:

```
try {
        String folderPath = context.getDir("folder_" + folderName, MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
        File outputDir = new File(folderPath);
        outputDir.mkdirs();
        File outputFile = new File(folderPath, imageName + ".webp");
        String filePath = outputFile.getAbsolutePath();
        outputFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 80, out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

logcat

```
2019-12-21 01:52:22.661 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@36339ee[EditActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
2019-12-21 01:52:22.892 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@36339ee[EditActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
2019-12-21 01:52:23.221 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@36339ee[EditActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
2019-12-21 01:52:23.257 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@36339ee[EditActivity]: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
2019-12-21 01:52:23.279 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@bcaaa08[EditActivity]: ThreadedRenderer.create() translucent=true
2019-12-21 01:52:23.287 22595-22595/me.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=252
2019-12-21 01:52:23.288 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@bcaaa08[EditActivity]: setView = DecorView@145f1ed[EditActivity] touchMode=true
2019-12-21 01:52:23.292 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@bcaaa08[EditActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-12-21 01:52:23.335 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@bcaaa08[EditActivity]: Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][0,0] newFrame=[84,852][996,1140] result=0x27 surface={isValid=true 2077935616} surfaceGenerationChanged=true
2019-12-21 01:52:23.335 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@bcaaa08[EditActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 2077935616} hwInitialized=true
2019-12-21 01:52:23.343 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@bcaaa08[EditActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2019-12-21 01:52:23.343 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@bcaaa08[EditActivity]: mHardwareRenderer.initializeIfNeeded()#2 mSurface={isValid=true 2077935616}
2019-12-21 01:52:23.344 22595-22595/me.myapp V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@f4905a1 nm : me.myapp ic=null
2019-12-21 01:52:23.344 22595-22595/me.myapp I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2019-12-21 01:52:23.346 22595-22595/me.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=275
2019-12-21 01:52:23.347 22595-22595/me.myapp D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=230
2019-12-21 01:52:23.371 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@bcaaa08[EditActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(84, 852 - 996, 1140) ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-12-21 01:52:23.418 22595-22595/me.myapp D/ViewRootImpl@36339ee[EditActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2019-12-21 01:52:23.447 22595-22642/me.myapp V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2019-12-21 01:52:23.496 22595-22607/me.myapp I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17946(1551KB) AllocSpace objects, 27(10MB) LOS objects, 20% free, 61MB/77MB, paused 4.249ms total 200.922ms
2019-12-21 01:52:25.085 22595-22595/me.myapp I/Choreographer: Skipped 92 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-12-21 01:52:25.228 22595-22655/me.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x7a980000 in tid 22655 (AsyncTask #3)
```

Comment: `outputFile.createNewFile();` Better remove that statement. The file will be created by the new FileOutputStream().

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: Do you mean logcat because there is not stacktrace for the error.

Comment: I added the logcat

Comment: Maybe you need to use Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP_LOSSLESS if the API level is 30 or above and use Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP if API is less than 30